# Know the lenght of a jquery scroll when I don't load all data in browser at once?

Tags: jquery, scroll, infinite-scroll

I use a query to retrieve 100 000+ rows for a database. I display this to the user in a table on his browser.

I don't want to load all this data into the browser at once. The height of each row is known and all row heights are the same. But I don't know the user's screen resolution.

Is it possible to determine the total height of the table and thus how long the scroll bar should be?

Comment: why you need to know this information? is it related to the logic that implements your infinite-scroll? it seems a XY-problem to me : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you should load approx. 20-30 rows by default and then use infinite-scroll jquery plugin so you do not have to worry about the scroll bar height and stuff. Hope this helps.

http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

Comment: Will I be able to go to say the middle of the table by dragging the scroll bar to the middle if I use infinite scroll?

Comment: No infinite scroll is used when you do not want to show that much data  all at once and do not want to use traditional pagination. Why do you want to load the entire 100000+ rows all at once as you would freeze the application?

Comment: If the query is for 100 000 rows and the user moves the scroll bar to the middle of the screen, I want the entries around 50 000 to be loaded into the browser.

Is this possible? I've heard before that infinite scroll can not determine the height of the table and thus I can move the scroll box to the middle to see the search results in the middle of my query.

Comment: I believe that you are not loading all the rows all at once. May be this is what you are looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/beKfX/

Answer (score -1):

A way to get the total height of the document could be like this

```
$(document).height();
```

Or for grapping the table height:

```
$('tableID').height();
```

But when do you insert more data from your query? I'll need a little more than what you have written to give a better answer..

Comment: I want to scroll bar to change every when I perform a new query. So if one query is 1000 rows and the next 10000 rows, then I want the box in the scroll bar to become 10x smaller